# React fill form, from send button open it

Tags: reactjs

I have a restaurant MySql database. In React I send new values in a form with node fetch. Adding a restaurant works fine. How would it be possible to open the created restaurant at the same time you press button to send the form? I guess it's very simple but I'm new to React. Restaurants are added to database with idRestaurant auto-increment.

Comment: what do you mean by opening the created restaurant? you should give more details of what you want.

Comment: I have a form where I give information about the new Restaurant name, address and so on. I press <button  className='createBox'type="submit">Create restaurant</button> and at the same time KI would like to open the created restaurant information, now the button just creates new restaurant.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to do. when you have a form in react you should have a state that keeps track of fields in that form. create a boolean state that indicates whether to show this information wherever you want it or not. after you submit the form if it was successful just make that boolean true and show restaurant info in your jsx whenever that boolean is true.
if this does not solve your problem then I didn't quite understand the question and try giving more accurate info next time with code snippets.